# Redirect index.php to root in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, magento-1.7

I installed Magento on my shared hosting server. I have made all the necessary changes in magento admin panel. All the url's work fine. But the only problem is I can access my products on the store using:

http://mydomain.com/category/product.html and also with http://mydomain.com/index.php/category/product.html

So I want to know how I can get rid of index.php. I want to redirect the url which consists of index.php to the url without index.php

Before posting here I checked the magento forums and also searched on stackoverflow but found no success.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can capture the part after `index.php` and redirect the client with

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.+)$ /$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php/?$ / [R,L]
```

This redirects all requests starting with `index.php/` to the URL without `index.php`. Additionally `index.php` and `index.php/` are redirected to the home page.

**Update**:

To exclude the admin area, you must insert an additional [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) before the first rule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/admin/
```

All together gives

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/admin/
RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.+)$ /$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php/?$ / [R,L]
```

Comment: Perfect! This help me. But the homepage did not redirect. Except that everything worked. I used this to redirect homepage http://sourcelibrary.org/2011/06/01/redirecting-index-php-to-root-using-htaccess/

Comment: @user1395787 I added a rule to redirect plain `index.php` to the home page.

Comment: hello, I have used the above code in my .htaccess but when I try to save anything in my magento admin dashboard nothing gets saved. But when I try to remove those last 2 lines from the htaccess file it works good. Can you tell me why?

Comment: @user1395787 When you remove the last two lines, you have no redirection anymore and nothing interferes with Magento's admin area. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Google is complaining about too many duplicate webpages. I have SEO URLS but anything with index.php will show the homepage without a redirect. I tried your code, but https://www.example.com/index.php?main_page=page_3 simply rewrites to https://www.example.com/?main_page=page_3 and it still see's it as a duplicate page.

Comment: @user2924019 If there's no redirect, maybe another rule interferes.

Comment: I tested the above code and its working fine but one big problem with the code. This code is forcing other URLs also to redirect to home page. I found the solution please check this link. https://infoconic.com/blog/magento-2-redirect-without-index.php-issue

Answer (score 4):

If you want to drop index.php from ALL links on your site, this solution actually worked the best for me:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /index.php/(.*) http://www.yourdomain.com/$1
```

Source:  http://www.lionseo.com/blog/htaccess-redirect-301/

Comment: This works for me but how to escape admin urls or every time redirect?

Comment: This will skip admin urls: `RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/((?!admin).*)$ /$1`. Furthermore the domain name is not required.

Comment: Single line in answer works for me perfectly and also no issues related to admin

Answer (score 0):

Using this you can escape the admin URL and redirect 301 index.php to without index.php url

```
RedirectMatch 301 /index.php/((?!admin).*)$1 http://www.example.com/$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Google always encourages the URL structure to be as simple as possible and redirects all live version of URLs to one preferred version. We can get this index.php problem easily fixed using some redirects code in htaccess file.

Problem with @Olaf solution.

The answer by Olaf works fine and it redirects the URLs from index.php to URLs without it but this code conflicts with other available redirects on the htaccess file. For example your website has one backlink from third party server coming to your domain https://example.com/product.html and for some reason you changed the URL from https://example.com/product.html to https://example.com/product2.html. Now to avoid lose in traffic and take advantage of that backlink, you may need to set a redirect on your htaccess file for this old URL https://example.com/product.html. This is because you can’t control third party server. Simply you will set a redirect to new path to avoid traffic lose.

Now here comes the problem, the @Olaf solution for index.php problem will set your all old redirects to root domain. Any other redirects available on htaccess file will be overwritten. To fix this problem, use the below code which is tested and works great. The below code redirects all URLs with index.php to URls without it and keep safe all old redirects on the .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php     
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Link - https://infoconic.com/blog/magento-2-redirect-without-index.php-issue/